# Play Framework Application and H2-browser

Tags: java, playframework, h2, typesafe-activator

We have to develop an application using Java Play Framework 2. There is a simple database calling H2, and we can browse it using h2-browser command in play console, but if an application compiled with 'dist' command, we didnotget access to the play console, but we need to debug database. So how can we access h2-browser without play console in 'dist' compiled application.

Thank you for answer.
p.s. Sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and run the *standalone* H2 engine and connect to it using ***ServerMode*** (from both: Play and browser), link and samples [available at H2 docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html).

Note performance will drop while using TCP connection so back to Embed solution after debugging if that matters to you.

Comment: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.M
essage:Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216"
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216" [90067-175]

Comment: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216"
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216" [90067-175]